# Что происходит когда сокет записывает данные в то время, когда с другой стороны читаются предыдущие данные?

Tags: c++, qt5, tcp, сокеты

К примеру у меня есть сокет, который в цикле (2 итерации к примеру) записывает данные подряд. При этом на другом конце (где этот сокет прослушивается) в это время происходит считывание. Так вот, что будет когда происходит вторая попытка записи данных в сокет, когда на другом конце еще считывается первая часть пересланых данных?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если сокет блокирующий и на чтение запрошено больше данных, чем Вы отправляете - будет ждать "второй итерации".
Если сокет неблокирующий - вычитает, сколько сможет, и затем Вам снова придется опрашивать сокет.

**В связи с комментарием @VTT хочу дать немного более развернутый ответ.**

---

Если вызывается одна из функций `read`/`recv`/`recvfrom` для блокируемого сокета и при этом в буфере нет никаких данных - сокет переходит в спящее состояние до тех пор, пока не придут какие-либо данные. Достаточно одного байта.

Тем не менее, мы можем задать флаг `MSG_WAITALL` - в этом случае мы будем ждать до тех пор, пока не будет доступно фиксированное (запрошенное нами) количество байт.

В случае неблокируемого сокета - если не удовлетворены условия ввода - то ф-ия вернет управление установив ошибку `EWOULDBLOCK`.

---

Если вызывается одна из функций `write`/`send`/`sendto` - данные копируются из буфера приложения в буфер отправки сокета. Для блокируемого сокета - если в буфере отправки недостаточно места, процесс переходит в состоянии оидания до тех пор, пока это самое место не освободится.

Для неблокируемого сокета - если в буфере отправки недостаточно места - ф-ия вернет управление, установив ошибку `EWOULDBLOCK`.

---

Комбинируйте и предполагайте наиболее вероятный результат того, чем же все-таки окончится посылка двух сообщений :)

Comment: Это многое объясняет. В случае неблокирующего сокета, какое количество данных может быть отправлено? Это какая-то константа?

Comment: @toall: Если ставите минусы - объясняйте за что. Необоснованное недовольство ответом делу не поможет.

Comment: то что нужно: применил блокировку до ответа от принимающей стороны и все заработало как нужно

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, Вы указываете размер в байтах одним из параметров, как в ф-ии read, так и в ф-ии write. Если я Вас правильно понял.

Comment: да, все верно. Я просто имею ввиду: какой максимальный размер данных можно запихнуть в сокет? Просто, как я понял, у меня проблема была в том, что в какой-то момент (на 45-ой итерации) применялся `socket->flush()` и дальше все записывалось уже в другой файловый дескриптор (если я все верно понял). Просто интересно, как система определяет, когда пора сделать flush (при том, что не было выхода из цикла)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, в Linux-based ОС есть параметр ядра, который задает размер буфера сокета

Comment: задавать буфер я не хочу, я хочу просто узнать минимальный размер, не подскажете как это сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону этого: getsockopt (SO_SNDBUF)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865069/how-to-find-the-socket-buffer-size-of-linux уже нашел

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Если у вас проблема решается блокировкой, то возможно что то не так. Если надо быстро отправлять и ответ прямо сейчас не требуется, то берете через select (или например epoll, смотря что у вас доступно), событие на "сокет доступен для записи" и когда оно возникакет - пишите, если возникает ошибка записи в сокет (записалось меньше, чем пытались) запоминаете на чем остановились и опять спите на select, пока тот не скажет, что в сокет можно писать

Comment: @Mike спасибо, но я пользуюсь Qt шными методами, а не напрямую через posix

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch В Qt должна быть какая то обертка для этого. Потому что обработка нескольких соединений в одном потоке обычно очень эффективна и много где используется

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, Mike прав, обычный поллинг сокетов - это как-то очень "просто", в лоб, в Qt наверняка должны были реализовать поддержку других способов опроса сокетов.

Comment: Минус потому что у вас чепуха написана. Успешная запись на первой итерации совершенно не означает, что данные дошли до клиента, или даже что они вообще куда-то ушли. А чтение даже на блокирующем сокете вполне может вычитывать за одну итерацию меньше данных, чем позволяет буфер приложения.

Comment: @VTT, не означает, Вы абсолютно правы. Про размеры отправляемых данных, размеры порции чтения и как все это накладывается на размер буфера - увы, я не подумал. Спасибо, что поправили. А вот второе Ваше предложение - извините, но перебор.

Comment: Второе предложение в комментарии @VTT абсолютно правильное. TCP это **поток байт**. Границы между вызовами, которые наполняли выходную очередь утрачиваются. При чтении вы получаете из системной очереди  в user space столько байт, сколько там есть  сейчас (конечно, не больше, чем запрошено) (исключение -- флаг [`MSG_WAITALL`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html) (впрочем,  он просто делает цикл в библиотечном вызове в user space))

Comment: @avp, отписался в ответе.

Answer (score 4):

В общем случае, попытки записи и чтения данных будут не связаны. Вторая попытка записи может происходить совершенно независимо от поведения (или даже от наличия) партнера на другой стороне. Более того, когда вызов функции записи на первой итерации успешно вернется, нет оснований полагать, что только что отправленные данные на самом деле куда-то ушли. Если активирован [алгоритм Нейгла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0), то только что посланные данные могут спокойно сидеть в буфере на стороне отправителя. Даже если подкрутить настройки (допустим `TCP_NODELAY`), то данные на момент второго вызова записи могут еще быть где-то в пути, или сидеть в буфере на принимающей стороне.